# Regex match any characters in string, up until next match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string: `title: one description: two`

and want to split it into groups like [`title: one`, `description: two`]

```
options.match(/(title|description):.+?/gi)
```

this was my attempt, but it only captures up to the : and 1 space after, it does not include the text after it, which I want to include all of, up until the second match.

Comment: `.+?` at the end of a pattern will always only match one char since it is non-greedy. In these cases, you must use lookarounds to tell the regex to match up to some point. Like, in your case, `(title|description)=(.*?)(?=\s*\w+:|$)`. Or, a bit more generalized ``([^\s=]+)=(.*?)(?=\s*\w+:|$)``. This pattern also matches multiword values, and allows quick access to both keys and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on a lookahead for `title` or `description`:

```js
const str = 'title: one description: two';
console.log(
  str.split(/ (?=title|description)/)
);
```

Comment: Nice, looks like it works! I considered using split at first, but then realize it removes what it matches so i switched to match. But I guess the lookahead isn't included in the match so it doesn't get removed, right? It's just matching a certain point in the string?

Comment: Right, with `/ (?=` the only thing that gets *matched* is the trailing space before the `title` or `description` - the lookahead section isn't matched, just looked for.

Answer (score 1):

You could also get the matches with a capture group and match the whitespace in between

```
(\b(?:title|description):.+?)\s*(?=\b(?:title|description):|$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\b(?:title|description):` Match either `title:` or `description:` and `:`
  - `.+?` Match 1+ times any char no greedy (lazy)
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is at the right is

  - `\b(?:title|description):|$` Match either `title:` or `description:` or assert the end of the string for the last item
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kuEYwm/1)

```js
const regex = /(\b(?:title|description):.+?)\s*(?=\b(?:title|description):|$)/gi;
let s = "title: one description: two";
console.log(Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var  str = "title: one description: two";

/* split with positive lookbehinds . A space must precede by all but :  */
var res=str.split(/(?<=[^:])\s/);
console.log(res);

/* match general rule  */
var res=str.match(/([^:\s]+:\s[^:\s]+)/gi);
console.log(res);

/* match with spacific words  */
var res=str.match(/((title|description)+:\s[^:\s]+)/gi);
console.log(res);
```